# Get Text from element inside a webtable without using XPath(Selenium Web driver + Java)

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

```
<table class="shoppingCart" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<!-- show if promo discount applied -->
<!-- end discount -->
<tr>
<td/>
<td/>
<th scope="row" colspan="2">Order total</th>
<td class="total ajaxCart_total"> $284.96  </td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
</table>
```

Can some one please help me with this?
I want to capture the text $284.96 in run time. And I do not want to use absolute Xpath(//table/tfoot/tr[4]/td[3]) as the page is dynamic and Xpath may change often.
How will I be able to this?

Thanks in Advance,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the class mentioned in the desired td is unique, You can go with xpath like this :

```
//td[@class='total ajaxCart_total']
```

Answer (score 1):

driver.findElement(By.className("total ajaxCart_total"))

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this xpath-

`"//table[@class='shoppingCart']//td[@class='total ajaxCart_total']"`

Answer (score 1):

if the table changes often, your best bet will be:

`//td[contains(@class,'total') and contains(@class, 'ajaxCart_total')]`

in this case if devs decide to add another css class you would still be safe.